# How to add an Eclipse CompareEditor inside a View?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, egit

How can I open an Eclipse CompareEditor inside a View?

More specifically, I want the view to contain a SashForm. In the left sash I put some information about the commit, and in the right sash  I want to put a compare editor that compares the commit to its parent. Is there such a thing even possible?

I've succeeded in using a GitCompareEditorInput from eGit and the CompareUI class to open a separate compare editor or a dialog with the compare editor (that compares a certain commit to its parent). But now I am interested in putting that compare editor inside another view, as detailed above.

Thanks

**Update**:
I have tried CompareEditorInput.createContents(compositeParent) but I only get two empty rectangles.

Comment: It's a bit of an overkill, since you'd have to re-implement all editor functionalities inside an editor component

Comment: eclipse.compare.internal.CompareDialog seems to be able to do it. Right now I am trying to reverse engineer the way it does it.

Answer (score 0):

The key to hosting a `CompareEditorInput` class appears to be providing a class which implements `org.eclipse.compare.ICompareContainer`. Once you have this you connect it to the input using `CompareEditorInput.setContainer(container)`.

`org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareContainer` provides a partial implementation of the container but this is **internal** so should only be used as a guide rather than used directly.